# Replace a string with first few characters

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

Let say I have a pattern like -

```
Str = "#sometext_any_character_including_&**(_etc_blabla\\s"
```

Now I want to replace above text with

```
"#some\\s"
```

i.e. I just want to retain `first 4 characters` and `trailing space` and `beginning #`. Is there any `r` way to do this?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would extract using regex. If you want all text following the `\\s` I would capture them with an ex:

```
import re

# Extract
pattern = re.compile("(#[a-z]{4}|\\\s)")
my_match = "".join(pattern.findall(my_string))
```

Comment: Oops, just seeing now that this Q is for `R` not python...

Answer (score 0):

An option with `sub`

```
sub("^(#.{4}).*(\\\\s)$", "\\1\\2", Str)
#[1] "#some\\s"
```

Answer (score -1):

str_replace(string, pattern, replacement)

or

str_replace_all(string, pattern, replacement)

You can use

Comment: I could use them, but in my case the replacement word is actually variable which is first few characters of supplied string

Comment: So you can use this for this.  substr(Str, start = 1, stop = 3) <- "writeforreplacement"